# Jackson BeanSerializerModifier.modifySerializer & interfaces that modify how a JsonSerializer is handled

Tags: jackson

Some interfaces, like `ResolvableSerializer` & `ContextualSerializer`, modify how Jackson handles a `JsonSerializer`.

Are there any other such interfaces?

Does Jackson ever modify its behavior for subclasses of `JsonSerializer`, like `StdSerializer`, `BeanSerializerBase`, or `BeanSerializer`? (other than via standard polymorphism, of course; I'm talking about things like `instanceof`, or `Class.isAssignableFrom()`, etc.)

In an implementation of `modifySerializer` in a subclass of `BeanSerializerModifier` that I wrote, I return a subclass of `JsonSerializer` that wraps the argument `JsonSerializer`.  This wrapper overrides only two methods:

- `serialize`: only if certain conditions are met does it call serialize on the wrapped serializer
- `getDelegatee`: returns the wrapped serializer

Questions:

1. should my wrapper extend some subclass of `JsonSerializer` instead of just `JsonSerializer`?

   1. if so, should the subclass depend on the class of the wrapped serializer?
2. should my wrapper overload any other methods?
3. should my wrapper implement the same serializer modifier interfaces as the wrapped serializer?  If so, then there are two problems:

   1. I have to know every modifier interface, and update my `BeanSerializerModifier` to handle any new ones that are added to Jackson
   2. I need to have a different wrapper class for each combination of modifier interfaces, which is very cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good questions. Here are some thoughts:

- Usually you should extend `StdSerializer` instead of "raw" `JsonSerializer`.
- If serialization is as JSON Scalar value, you may want to extend `StdScalarSerializer`
- Base type does not need to match, in general, although if delegating to `Collection` or `Map` serializers you may want to do that -- however, in general, you should need matching. It would get impractical soon as you correctly note.
- On overloading: there are a few methods you may choose to overload, and usually just delegate to delegatee:

  - For polymorphic handling, define "serializeWithType(...)"
  - `isEmpty()`, if there are non-null values that correlate with concept of "empty": for example, String "" is considered empty.
  - `acceptJsonFormatVisitor()` is necessary to support JSON Schema generation and other type introspection (like generating Avro, CSV and Protobuf schemas, using matching data format modules)

Comment: I'm still not clear about how I should handle ResolvableSerializer & ContextualSerializer. I've seen Jackson code that checks if a serializer is an instanceof one of the interfaces. If so, then it casts & calls an interface method. I haven't seen such code check if the delegatee is an instanceof. So, if I want my wrapper to be as transparent as possible, it must implement all of these marker interfaces that the delegatee implements, right? If there are only 2 marker interfaces, that means that I must have 4 versions of my wrapper class. I must add more whenever another marker is added, right?

Comment: Since I'm overriding BeanSerializerModifier.modifySerializer, will the JsonSerializer argument always be a BeanSerializer? If so, then can my wrapper extend BeanSerializer instead of StdSerializer?  BeanSerializer already implements both of the marker interfaces of which I am aware, so I'd only need one version of my class instead of the 4 versions required to support all possible marker interface combinations for StdSerializer (one each for implementing none, Resolvable-only, Contextual-only, and both).

Comment: Lastly, I'm gonna ask a whole new Jackson question on SO, since I investigated all this stuff for a higher-level functionality that I couldn't find in Jackson. But maybe it exists, and I missed it.  I'll link to that question once I've posted it. Thanks again for all the help, and for Jackson.

Comment: Question about the higher-level feature that I was trying to implement via BeanSerializerModifier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859551/jackson-exclude-object-from-serialization-based-on-its-properties

Comment: I tried to write a `ForwardingBeanSerializer` class that extends `BeanSerializerBase`, overrides `getDelegatee()` with a covariant return type of `BeanSerializerBase`, and delegates all methods defined in `JsonSerializer`, `StdSerializer` & `BeanSerializerBase` to `getDelegatee()`. This didn't work, however, because many of the methods are protected, so while my wrapper class can override the methods, it can't call them on the delegatee. Could all of those methods be made public, so that my  wrapper can call them on its delegatee? Or should I not be delegating the protected methods?

Comment: Ok, first things first. If you want to delegate to all kinds of things, yes, you do want to implement `ResolvableSerializer` and `ContextualSerializer`, and then dynamically determine if you need to dispatch. There is no need NOT to implement them; calls are blind and only there for serializer's benefit; caller does not care.