# Jackson: exclude object from serialization based on its properties

Tags: jackson

What is the easiest way in Jackson to exclude an object from serialization based on its properties?

e.g., say an instance `o` of class `C` has a `boolean enabled` field.  If `o.enabled == false`, then the object shouldn't be serialized.

Also, how can I make this work in conjunction with the current JSON View? e.g., say an instance `o` of class `C` has a `boolean topSecret` field.  If `o.topSecret == true`, and if the current JSON View is not `TopSecret.class`, then the object shouldn't be serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct functionality for doing this, because the way serialization works, value objects themselves can not decide if they want to be serialized or not. This is mostly because property name may already have been written, so something must be written as a value.
Rather, it is Object properties that determine inclusion/exclusion.

With this, JSON Filters (http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html) could perhaps work for you. JSON Views are too static to allow level of control.

Another possibility could be to try to use machinery that deals with `@JsonInclude`. `JsonSerializer` has `isEmpty(...)` method that is used to check whether object of type serializer handles is considered "empty", and possibly excluded from serialization. If number of types you need to handle is limited, this might work. However based on the original question this is probably not the case.

Yet another possibility is to do two-phase processing: first convert POJOs into Tree Model (`JsonNode`), then traverse it, remove whatever should not be included. And after this, serialize tree model.

Comment: If I understand `@JsonFilter` correctly, if applied to type `T`, it selectively filters properties of `T`; if applied to property `p` of `T`, it selectively filters  `p`.  If that's correct, then `@JsonFilter` won't work for me, since I want to selectively filter any value of type `V` from any property `p` of any type `T`, without explicitly annotating all `p` & `T`.  I even want to filter instances of `V` if they're elements in a serialized `Collection` or `Map`, or if instances of type `V` are values for properties that are superclasses of `V`, like a property whose type is `Object`

Comment: I don't think I can use the `@JsonInclude` / `isEmpty()` scheme, since I might need to include "empty" values for properties of other types (e.g., I might want to output `null` values for certain properties, or empty arrays / maps for other properties)

Comment: @XDR you are probably right since you know requirements better than I do, and have looked at interfaces involved. I just wanted to mention these as potential routes. The next route you could consider would be registering `BeanSerializerModifier` and/or `BeanDeserializerModifier` (via `Module`). These allow either changing property handlers wholesale (add/remove), or wrapping specific ones you want to with additional logic. They are more work, but also expose full power of modifying handling of individual properties without fully custom (de)serializer.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I actually started with `BeanSerializerModifier` before asking this question, but kept running into issues, so I figured that maybe I had gone about it wrong.  But I think I have everything working now using `BeanSerializerModifier`.

Comment: @XDR right, I only realized afterwards that there were related discussions on number of permutations needed and such.