# Exclude/remove field from parsed JSON

Tags: java, json

I'm calling a web service passing JSON and getting back JSON. I'm trying to log requests and responses for troubleshooting purposes. I'd like to exclude or cross-out (via *) any password values identified by a field name regex or something. I'm using Gson for my JSON parsing and serialization. I'm including the following `toJson` method call in my `logRequest` and `logResponse` methods:

```
private String toJson(String str) {
    JsonElement elt = JSON_PARSER.parse(str);
    return GSON.toJson(elt);
}
```

I don't see anything that will help me on the `JsonParser` object. I've tried various approaches when constructing the `Gson` instance via `GsonBuilder` to no avail. The difficulty with that approach seems to be the fact that I'm not mapping to POJOs that would allow me to use an `ExclusionStrategy`. My current thought is to recursively inspect the `JsonElement` I get back from the `parse` method, but I'm not sure that will work and feels heavy-handed so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your requirement in a generic way is going to be difficult due to the way generic JSON serialisation works. Somebody had already asked a similar question here: [Jackson: exclude object from serialization based on its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859551/jackson-exclude-object-from-serialization-based-on-its-properties).
It looks like traversing over JSON objects after parsing the JSON string, identifying the password fields and explicitly sanitising the values before serialising back into string for the logger might be a good choice, if you prefer to follow this path.

However, the problem can be solved much easier provided you know the json schema of the document you want to log. In this situation, you could generate Java Pojo objects from the schema using **`jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin`** and then use `Gson` library with serialisation exclusion strategy. Here is an example:

```
    String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"parent\",\"id\":\"parentId\",\"password\":\"topsecret\"" +
            ",\"childPojo\":{\"name\":\"child\",\"id\":\"childId\",\"password\":\"topsecret\"}}";

    RegexFieldExclusionStrategy strategy = new RegexFieldExclusionStrategy("pass.*");

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(strategy)
            .create();

    MyPojo myPojo = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyPojo.class);

    String json = gson.toJson(myPojo);
    System.out.println(json);
```

**MyPojo** class:

```
public class MyPojo {

  private String name;
  private String id;
  private String password;
  private MyPojo childPojo;

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
  public String getId() {
      return id;
  }
  public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
  }
  public String getPassword() {
      return password;
  }
  public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
  }
  public MyPojo getChildPojo() {
      return childPojo;
  }
  public void setChildPojo(MyPojo childPojo) {
      this.childPojo = childPojo;
  }
}
```

Note this `Pojo` is a manual implementation and can be replaced with a generated one, using the plugin mentioned above, in order to streamline the whole process.

**RegexFieldExclusionStrategy** class:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy;
import com.google.gson.FieldAttributes;

public class RegexFieldExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

  private String regex;

  public RegexFieldExclusionStrategy(String regex) {
      Pattern.compile(regex);
      this.regex = regex;
  }

  public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> f) {
      return false;
  }

  public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
      return f.getName().toLowerCase().matches(regex);
  }
}
```

The program will output the following JSON document:

```
{"name":"parent","id":"parentId","childPojo":{"name":"child","id":"childId"}}
```